# Using Web3 1.0 with React Native

Tags: web3js

> This question has already been asked but has never received a clear answer. Plus, the questions are old and in the blockchain space, a one-year old question is obsolete. This question is for React **Native and version 0.51 and web3 version 1.0-beta**

Hi,

I am trying to create a React Native application that uses web3js but I am unable to actually import it. The error is pretty obvious but I don't know how to solve it.

```
attempted to import the Node standard library module "crypto". It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library.
```

Is the error due to Expo? Should I eject? Have anyone actually solved this?

Thanks,
Dario

Answer (score 5):

There is some documentation about React Native that will help you understand why some packages are not possible to be included into React Native applications.

> if the package depends on Node standard library APIs, you will not be
> able to use it with Expo. The Node standard library is a set of
> functionality implemented largely in C++ that exposes functions to
> JavaScript that aren't part of the JavaScript language specification,
> such as the ability to read and write to your filesystem. React
> Native, and by extension Expo, do not include the Node standard
> library, just like Chrome and Firefox do not include it. JavaScript is
> a language that is used in many contexts, from mobile apps (in our
> case), to servers, and of course on websites. These contexts all
> include their own runtime environments that expose different APIs to
> JavaScript, depending on what makes sense in the context.
> [ref](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq.html#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo)

That said, you can try to include the **dist files** instead of the package. When you include the package via Nodejs, it will be compiled (if it's required) and possibly use some Node standard libraries.

You can find the **web3 dist** [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/1.0/dist), and since it's pure JavaScript (that will run in the browser), it should work also in React Native, according to [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html).

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong but this approach doesn't work. But the explanation is accurate. I think the way to fix this is to shim the "crypto" package

Comment: crypto is a Node Standard library: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html so you have some modules that use this dependency and that's why you are having the described error. So just uninstall the packages and use the dist. Provided that the issue is related to web3 and not other dependencies

Comment: I already said that it does not work. Please do not answer if you haven't tried. Using the dist is not the solution. I think that the solution is to eject, install react-native-crypto and use rn-nodeify to shim it. I'll let you know when I make it work.

Comment: I tried to help you, but if you already know the solution then that's better. cheers

Answer (score 3):

Just something missing in @Andy Malkin answer:
add **global.js** file

```
// Inject node globals into React Native global scope.

global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');

if (typeof btoa === 'undefined') {
  global.btoa = function(str) {
    return new Buffer(str, 'binary').toString('base64');
  };
}

if (typeof atob === 'undefined') {
  global.atob = function(b64Encoded) {
    return new Buffer(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('binary');
  };
}
```

then import it in the app.js

```
import "./global"
```

Answer (score 2):

I covered this in a blog post a little while ago for the web3 0.20.x line: https://medium.com/@generalpiston/how-to-react-native-w-web3-0x-js-0xconnect-39b3d6a4dca.

The steps are roughly the same for the web3 1.x line as well.

Several node.js libraries are missing in react-native and isomorphic-fetch doesn’t work well with react-native. To get it working, follow these steps:

1. npm i -S abec/node-libs-react-native.
2. Add the following to rn-cli.config.js:

> const extraNodeModules = require("node-libs-react-native");
>
> module.exports = {
>     extraNodeModules
>   };

3. Add the following to the top of your root index.js file:

> import "node-libs-react-native/globals";

4. Add the following config to your package.json under the scripts section:

> "prepare": "npm run patch",
>
> "patch": "find ./node_modules -name fetch-npm-browserify.js -print -exec sed -i.bk 's/self/global/g' {} \;"

Answer (score 1):

i got web3 up and running with RN59 and React 16.8

`react-native init APPNAME`

`npm i --save react-native-crypto`

`npm i --save react-native-randombytes`

`react-native link react-native-randombytes`

`npm i --save-dev rn-nodeify@latest`

`./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --install`

`npm i --save node-libs-browser`

## modify APPNAME/metro.config.js to read:

```
const extraNodeModules = require('node-libs-browser');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    extraNodeModules,
  },
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

## modify shim.js to read:

```
if (typeof __dirname === 'undefined') global.__dirname = '/'
if (typeof __filename === 'undefined') global.__filename = ''
if (typeof process === 'undefined') {
  global.process = require('process')
} else {
  const bProcess = require('process')
  for (var p in bProcess) {
    if (!(p in process)) {
      process[p] = bProcess[p]
    }
  }
}

process.browser = false
if (typeof Buffer === 'undefined') global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer

if (typeof location === 'undefined') global.location = { port: 80, protocol: 'https:' }
const isDev = typeof __DEV__ === 'boolean' && __DEV__
process.env['NODE_ENV'] = isDev ? 'development' : 'production'
if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
  localStorage.debug = isDev ? '*' : ''
}

// If using the crypto shim, uncomment the following line to ensure
// crypto is loaded first, so it can populate global.crypto
require('crypto')
```

import './shim' in App.js

`npm i --save web3`

`react-native run-ios`

enter /ios folder
`pod install`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like some others were successful:

> ## How to set up web3.js with CRNA
>
> This is a simple guide to get you started with using the `Ethereum
>   Javascript API` ([web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)) with
>   the `Create React Native App` project. This is not an in-depth guide.
>
> #### TL;DR If you are lazy and just want to get started, I have [this project](https://github.com/dougbacelar/react-native-web3) ready for
>
> you. It should **work out-of-the-box**.
>
> #### Installation guide
>
> 1. Make sure you have Node version 6 or later installed, if not, get it on the Node website
>
>    `node --version`
> 2. Install Create React Native App
>
>    `npm install -g create-react-native-app`
> 3. Use create-react-native-app to create the project boilerplate
>
>    `create-react-native-app my-app`
> 4. Install `node-libs-browser` (redacted link because of reputation)
>
>    `npm install --save node-libs-browser`
> 5. Create a file called *rn-cli.config.js* on the root of the project and add the following code into it:
>
>    ```javascript
>        const extraNodeModules = require('node-libs-browser');
>
>    module.exports = {
>          extraNodeModules,
>        };  ```
> 6. Create a file called *global.js* on the root of the project and add the following code into it:
>
>    ```javascript
>      // Inject node globals into React Native global scope.    global.Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;   global.process =
>      require('process');       if (typeof btoa === 'undefined') {
>      global.btoa = function (str) {
>        return new Buffer(str, 'binary').toString('base64');      };    }
>
>    if (typeof atob === 'undefined') {    global.atob = function
>      (b64Encoded) {
>        return new Buffer(b64Encoded, 'base64').toString('binary');       };    }
>
>    ```
> 7. Import the *global.js* file into your *App.js* file
>
>    `javascript
>        import './global';`
> 8. Install [babel-preset-es2015](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2015)
>        `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`
> 9. Now we can install the [web3.js api](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/)
>
>    `npm install --save web3`
> 10. Require the API in your `App.js` file
>
>     `javascript
>       const Web3 = require('web3');`
> 11. Add the following code inside your React component in `App.js` to get started with consuming the API. The code will print information of
>       the latest block on the console.
>
>     ```javascript
>       componentWillMount() {
>         const web3 = new Web3(
>           new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('link redacted because of reputation limit')
>         );
>
>     web3.eth.getBlock('latest').then(console.log)
>       }     ```
> 12. Test it
>
>     `npm start`
>
>     or
>         `npm run ios`
>
>     or
>
>     `npm run android`
>
> For more examples on the API usage, visit the web3.js API.
>
> For a project with all this setup ready, check out [link redacted because of link limit on reputation).

## Sources:

https://gist.github.com/dougbacelar/29e60920d8fa1982535247563eb63766
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1022